# Double brackets for and operators in SQL Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

The following codes have been using at my company for awhile, and I was wondering what the double brackets do. Thank you!

**where ((TableA.COl1 >= '2014-01-01'  AND TableB.COL2_key IS NULL)    ) AND
    TableC.COL3 <> '04'**

Comment: i would say : nothing, not sure though

Comment: Since you've got nothing but ands (no ors) the parens do nothing.

Comment: I prefer triple brackets, they're more secure :-)

Comment: likely an artifact, some of the where clause may have been removed, second bracket layer remained.